# View Existing Table-valued Parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, table-valued-parameters

I have seen many tutorials on how to create a table-valued parameter - but how do you view a table-valued parameter after it has been created?

I would prefer a way of using the GUI in SSMS but T-SQL would suffice as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use this code to create a table value Parameter.

```
--create a new database
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE DemoTVP
GO


--Change context to the new databse
USE [DemoTVP]
GO

--creating table-Valued Parameters
CREATE TYPE LocationTableType AS TABLE   
( LocationName VARCHAR(50)  
, CostRate INT );  
GO
```

Then you see the above created table value parameter in SSMS.

[image]

Using TSQL you can see the same.

```
USE [DemoTVP]
GO
SELECT * FROM [sys].[objects]
WHERE [type] ='TT'
ORDER BY create_date DESC
```